# Ember.js problems binding content of array controller to content of a different array controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, ember.js, controllers

We're having trouble linking the content of one array controller with the content of another array controller in Ember.js.  We've scoured Stackoverflow, but no solution seems to work for us.

The scenario is simple.  We have a model called "Campaign".  The model is pretty basic and looks like this...

**Campaign Model:**

```
App.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({

    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    opts: DS.attr('string'),
    starred: DS.attr('boolean'),
    keywords: DS.hasMany('App.Keyword')

});

// Create dummy campaign array

App.Campaign.FIXTURES = new Array();

// Populate dummy campaign array

...
```

The Campaign controller is also basic.  It's a simple ArrayController with nothing going on inside it ...

**Campaign Index Controller:**

```
App.CampaignsIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

For the sake of this question, we've stripped our application template down to the essentials.  As you can see below, the application template has a sidebar.  In the sidebar are two views.  One view is for the site's navigation, the other view is for "Starred Campaigns".  This view will contain a subset of the overall collection of campaigns.

**Application Template:**

```
<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- ======================= APP ====================== -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<div id="app" class="">

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- ==================== SIDEBAR ===================== -->
    <!-- ================================================== -->

    <div id="sidebar">

        {{ view App.NavigationView }}

        {{ view App.StarredCampaignsView controller="App.StarredCampaignsController" }}

    </div>

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- ====================== PAGE ====================== -->
    <!-- ================================================== -->

    <div id="page" class="">

        {{ outlet page }}

    </div>

</div>
```

We have a controller for Starred Campaigns.  This is where things start to get confusing.  In our controller, we bind the content of the ArrayController to the content of the CampaignsIndexController, which holds the array of all Campaign models.

**Starred Campaigns Controller:**

```
App.StarredCampaignsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

    content: [],

    contentBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.CampaignsIndexController.content')

});
```

The view of for Starred Campaigns is also very simple...

**Starred Campaigns View:**

```
App.StarredCampaignsView = Em.View.extend({

    templateName: 'templates/layout/starred-campaigns',

});
```

And this is what the template for Starred Campaigns looks like.  It is attempting to loop over the items in the controller.content and pass them off to another view.

**Starred Campaigns Template:**

```
<h5 class="sidebar-title">Starred Campaigns</h5>

<ul class="starred-campaigns clearfix">

    {{# each item in controller.content }}

        {{ view App.StarredCampaignItemView itemBinding="item" }}

    {{/ each }}

</ul>
```

However, despite all of this, the content in StarredCampaignsController remains empty, even when we populate the App.Campaign array that is represent by App.CampaignsIndexController.  See any problems with our approach?  I feel like we're missing something really simple here.

Comment: There's also a better way to insert views like that. Take your `NavigationView`, you're rendering it well enough in the page, but wouldn't it be better if it had its own controller? If you use: `{{render "navigation"}}`, then Ember will automatically place `App.NavigationView` in there, and it will have access to `App.NavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ember, for controllers to require other controllers, you need to use the `needs` property. This is always changing in Ember: in previous versions it was the responsibility of the router with `this.controllerFor`, and with even older versions, the approach was more akin to the approach you appear to be attempting to take. However, the final approach has long since been deprecated, and instances of controllers/models/views are no longer held on `App` directly, only their **object** representations.

To dive straight in with the `need`s, you need to tell your `App.StarredCampaignsController` controller that it requires the `App.CampaignsIndexController` like so:

```
App.StarredCampaignsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    needs: ['campaigns_index']
});
```

You now have access to the `App.CampaignsIndexController` controller in your starred campaigns view: `{{controllers.campaigns_index}}`.

*See simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AGJfB/*

The reason why yours isn't working is because you've reference the object of the controller, as opposed to its instance:

```
Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.CampaignsIndexController.content')
```

Whilst you have an `App.CampaignsIndexController` on `App`, that's its object. Ember will create the instance for you when you access it through any of the Ember ways (`this.controllerFor`, `needs`, navigating to it via the URL, etc...).

In days gone by we could use:

```
Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.campaignsIndexController.content')
```

However, that's such a bad way to do things, because you're referencing an absolute path to the controller. Ever since Ember pre 1, I've never had to use `Ember.Binding.oneWay`, but there still will be cases where you need it. When you find yourself using it though, it's probably wise to ask yourself if it's necessary, and whether there's a better way to do it.

I hope I've explained myself well. Please feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: thanks for the tip on `{{ render "" }}`.  It work beautifully.  However, now I'm confused on the proper approach to access the content from `App.CampaignsIndexController` inside my template.

Comment: In my template, I have `{{ controllers.campaigns_index }}` which prints out `<App.CampaignsIndexController:ember440>`.  Which is great, because that means it has knowledge of the controller instance. But, when looping through content `{{# each item in controllers.campaigns_index.content }} {{ item }} {{/ each }}` nothing is printed.  Maybe because this template is rendered before the content of `App.CampaignsIndexController` is populated with data, there is nothing to display.  This was my original thought on why binding would be useful, because it would trigger and update.  Any thoughts here?

Comment: Sadly you've run into a current Ember bug: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2025 By specifying the underscore, we're getting the controller, but it's a difference instance of it. We should be using the dot notation (`needs: ['campaigns.index];`) but we can't at the moment due to the bug.

Comment: is there any documentation on the `needs` parameter?  I can't seem to find it on Ember.js's site.  If this were working, how would I reference the content in the template?

Comment: Not at the moment, since it's quite a recent addition, but they're always updating the documentation. If it *were* working, then it'd be like so: `{{controllers.index}}` because if `IndexController` extended `ArrayController` then it would delegate to `content`.

Comment: So, instead we'd say `needs: ['campaigns.index']` and in the template we'd reference the content with `{{controllers.index}}`?  I'm assuming this is bound to updates on App.CampaignsIndexControllers content?  Since this is buggy, is there an older approach that will work in the interim?

Comment: That's right. I'd go for `this.controllerFor` for the time being, and when `this.controllerFor` is **@deprecated** in pre 5, this bug should be fixed as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  Where would I place `this.controllerFor`?

Comment: Sorry. You'd have to stuff it into the `setupController` for the appropriate route: http://jsfiddle.net/AGJfB/1/

Comment: I'm using needs with a camelcase notation and it seems to be working as expected:

`needs: ['campaignsIndex']`
`{{each item in controllers.campaignsIndex}}`